# Placing a text over an image

Tags: html, css

I can't think of a good way to place text over an image. Here is what I want to do:

This is what I have. I want to place text over the yellow navigation signs on the left (like normal navigation of Home, Contact Us, About Us, etc...) but I can't really think of a good way to do that. I tried doing it the same what I put the actual signs their with absolute position, but didn't work out. Also I plan on putting text over the blue bar in the middle of the page, but that will be done in the same way.

I dont NEED the letters themselves to be links to the next pages, but if that is what happens when I put the text over it, then so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a span right where your image is and have it set as position absolute with a top and left to place it in the right spot. Here is an example to try with the top of the posts on the pole to get the text test in the middle of it:

```
<a href="index.html">
 <img src="images/rightArrow.png" id="img2">
 <span style="position:absolute;left:95px;top:33px">test</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could potentially incorporate the image as part of a background. I'm fairly new to this and therefore have limited knowledge, but adding all of those images into a single "background-image" CSS attribute may be your best bet.

Comment: I dont want to do that as those signs are going to be interactive. When they get hovered the green border will show up, when they are actively being clicked, they will flip (or something along those lines). So i dont want to send them all on the same layer

Comment: @LiverpoolFTW: All still possible if the image is a background image.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/UMtXy/1/

You can position each element individually, add hover styles, change the background, etc.
    ​

### HTML

*(more semantic than just using DIVs)*

```
<nav>
   <ul>
    <li>Some Text</li>
    <li>Some Text</li>
    <li>Some Text</li>
    <li><a href="#">Links can go here too</a></li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

### CSS

```
NAV LI{
    background-image:url(http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~ageoffri/unavitSite/images/rightArrow.png);    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    padding: 12px 32px;
    font: 12px/12px arial, sans-serif;
}

NAV LI:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

As mike jones have said you would use css variables background/background-image which would simply be 1 sign post and you would repeat this class but only change the text in for example:

**CSS Style Code (must add in):**

```
.yellowarrow{
background: url(http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~ageoffri/unavitSite/images/leftArrow.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 170px;
height: 35px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

**Replace:**

```
<img src="images/leftArrow.png" id="img3" /><img src="images/leftArrow.png" id="img4" /><img src="images/leftArrow.png" id="img5" /><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/leftArrow.png" id="img6" /></a>
```

**With:**

```
    <div class="yellowarrow">Menu 1</div>
<div class="yellowarrow">Menu 2</div>
<div class="yellowarrow">Menu 3</div>
<div class="yellowarrow">Menu 4</div>
<div class="yellowarrow">Menu 5</div>
<div class="yellowarrow"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></div>
```

Personally this would be the most convenient way to do this, I would also recommend using onclick options on the menu DIV(s) instead of the href around the text.

Comment: Hmm, ill look into the onclick. never used it before.